# Cyclic inequality with fractions

Tags: functional-inequalities

Let $x,y,z\geq0$. Show that $x^4(y+z)+y^4(z+x)+z^4(x+y)\leq\frac{1}{12}(x+y+z)^5$

Comment: What have you tried? Can you find an equality case?

Comment: I tried to find a convex function and then aplying Jensen's inequality

Comment: Find the equality case first (which would then suggest that Jensen's isn't easy to apply).

Comment: Yes,I saw that if x=y=z,all of them have to be 0 in order to obtain equality.I tried to take x+y+z=1 WLOG but i don't have other ideas

Comment: Can you help me, please?

Comment: Take $ x = 0 $ and find the equality case with $ y + z = 1$.

Comment: y=$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$ or $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: I think that now I know how to prove it if $x=0$ by creating a perfect square.Can you help me please if $x>0$?

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: Any idea, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \geqslant y \geqslant z$ and
$$f(x,y,z) = x^4(y+z)+y^4(z+x)+z^4(x+y).$$
We have
$$\begin{aligned}f(x,y,z)-f(x,y+z,0) & = y^4(z+x)+z^4(x+y)-x(y+z)^4\\ \\& = y^4(z+x)+z^4(x+y)-x(y+z)^4 \\ \\&=-yz\left[3x(y+z)^2+y^2(x-y)+z^2(x-z)\right] \leqslant 0.\end{aligned}.$$
Therefore $f(x,y,z) \leqslant f(x,y+z,0).$ Finally, we need to prove
$$f(x,y+z,0) = x^4(y+z)+x(y+z)^4\leqslant \frac{1}{12}(x+y+z)^5.$$
Setting $a = y +z,$ the inequality become
$$12ax(a^3+x^3) \leqslant (x+a)^5,$$
or
$$(a+x)(a^2-4ax+x^2)^2 \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true. The proof is completed.